# Regex string exclusion

Tags: regex

I can't find how to exclude a string in my regex :

ex :

```
<div\s[^>]+>
```

will find a `<div` and every characters before its closing `>`

Now I would like to find the `<div...>` then `everything but a </div>` then a `</div>`. Something like :

```
 <div\s[^>]+>[^(</div>)]*</div>
```

The problem is `[^abc]` is excluding a or b or c. How can I exclude the "abc" string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what [negative lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) are for:

```
<div\s[^>]+>(?:(?!</div>).)*</div>
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?:          # Match...
 (?!</div>)  # unless we're right before a </div>
 .           # any character.
)*           # Repeat as needed
```

You might want to make the slash optional (`(?!</?div>)`); otherwise you would trip up on nested tags like in `<div> foo <div> bar </div> baz </div>`.

Comment: u way too fast..i barely type

Answer (score 1):

Using non-greedy regex its possible

```
<div\s[^>]+>(.*?)</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain why it's working? (i though `?` was for 0 or 1 time the last char)

Comment: in non-greedy expression, . does not match *all* it stops right before if finds match in the pattern.

Comment: Ok, found it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression : `By using a lazy quantifier, the expression tries the minimal match first`